# Batch For loop to get first value

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing a batch file and I want to run a for loop that sets it's first value to a variable. I only need the first value of a command but I couldn't find another way to do this. The way I have it set up is with a for loop then a do statement that says if variable is not set, set variable. The issue is when this runs, the loop uses the unset variable every time instead of treating it as set after the first loop.

For example, my if says `if "%foo%"=="" set foo=%%i` and the output looks like this 
`if "" == "" set foo="hello"` the next loop will still say `if "" == "" set foo="bar"`

Is there a way to get around this? I tried setting delayed expansion and that didn't help. I'm also open to other ways that will give me only the first value from a command.

Comment: Please put here what you've tried so far.

Comment: Delayed expansion would have worked if you enabled it, and changed `%foo%` to `!foo!`

Comment: Answer below worked. I tried with delayed expansion with ! but I may have had to use more escape characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
set "foo="
for /f %%i in (....) do if not defined foo set "foo=%%i"
```

Or, if you can add a label

```
for /f %%i in (....) do set "foo=%%i" & goto :done
:done
```

Comment: Is the first line in the first solution here (ie `set "foo="`) just an insurance to make sure the variable `foo` is indeed not set?

Comment: @Tim, I'm using the `defined` state of the variable (if it has any value) to determine if it is the first iteration. Yes, I need to be sure the variable is not defined.

Comment: @MCND thanks - I guess I was assuming you'd make your script tidy enough that you'd know it hadn't already been set, but I suppose you might have already used that variable for something else that you'd be happy to overwrite now.